# How to draw a radar plot in ggplot using polar coordinates?

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

I am trying to use ggplot to draw a radar-chart following the guidelines from the Grammar of Graphics. I am aware of the [ggradar](https://github.com/ricardo-bion/ggradar) package but based on the grammar it looks like `coord_polar` should be enough here. This is the pseudo-code from the grammar:

[image]

So I thought something like this may work, however, the contour of the area chart is curved as if I used `geom_line`:

```
library(tidyverse)
dd <- tibble(category = c('A', 'B', 'C'), value = c(2, 7, 4))
ggplot(dd, aes(x = category, y = value, group=1)) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'x') +
  geom_area(color = 'blue', alpha = .00001) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

While I understand why `geom_line` draws arcs once in `coord_polar`, my understanding of the explanation from the Grammar of Graphics is that there may be an element/geom `area` that could plot straight lines:

> here is one technical detail concerning the shape of Figure 9.29. Why
>   is the outer edge of the area graphic a set of straight lines instead
>   of arcs? The answer has to do with what is being measured. Since
>   region is a categorical variable, the line segments linking regions
>   are not in a metric region of the graph. That is, the segments of the
>   domain between regions are not measurable and thus the straight lines
>   or edges linking them are arbitrary and perhaps not subject to
>   geometric transformation. There is one other problem with the
>   grammatical specification of this figure. Can you spot it? Undo the
>   polar trans- formation and think about the domain of the plot. We
>   cheated.

For completeness, this question derives from [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032447/how-to-draw-a-point-in-polar-coordinates-with-negative-r?noredirect=1#comment100923265_57032447) question I asked about plotting in polar system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2: connecting points in polar coordinates with a straight line 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562128/ggplot2-connecting-points-in-polar-coordinates-with-a-straight-line-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr we can write a function to solve this problem.

Indeed, ggplot uses a process called data munching for non-linear coordinate systems  to draw lines. It basically breaks up a straight line in many pieces, and applies the coordinate transformation on the individual pieces instead of merely the start- and endpoints of lines.

If we look at the panel drawing code of for example `GeomArea$draw_group`:

```
    function (data, panel_params, coord, na.rm = FALSE) 
{
    ...other_code...
    positions <- new_data_frame(list(x = c(data$x, rev(data$x)), 
        y = c(data$ymax, rev(data$ymin)), id = c(ids, rev(ids))))
    munched <- coord_munch(coord, positions, panel_params)
    ggname("geom_ribbon", polygonGrob(munched$x, munched$y, id = munched$id, 
        default.units = "native", gp = gpar(fill = alpha(aes$fill, 
            aes$alpha), col = aes$colour, lwd = aes$size * .pt, 
            lty = aes$linetype)))
}
```

We can see that a `coord_munch` is applied to the data before it is passed to `polygonGrob`, which is the grid package function that matters for drawing the data. This happens in almost any line-based geom for which I've checked this.

Subsequently, we would like to know what is going on in `coord_munch`:

```
function (coord, data, range, segment_length = 0.01) 
{
    if (coord$is_linear()) 
        return(coord$transform(data, range))
    ...other_code...
    munched <- munch_data(data, dist, segment_length)
    coord$transform(munched, range)
}
```

We find the logic I mentioned earlier that non-linear coordinate systems break up lines in many pieces, which is handled by `ggplot2:::munch_data`.

It would seem to me that we can trick ggplot into transforming straight lines, by somehow setting the output of `coord$is_linear()` to always be true.

Lucky for us, we wouldn't have to get our hands dirty by doing some deep ggproto based stuff if we just override the `is_linear()` function to return `TRUE`:

```
# Almost identical to coord_polar()
coord_straightpolar <- function(theta = 'x', start = 0, direction = 1, clip = "on") {
  theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
  r <- if (theta == "x") 
    "y"
  else "x"
  ggproto(NULL, CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start,
          direction = sign(direction), clip = clip,
          # This is the different bit
          is_linear = function(){TRUE})
}
```

So now we can plot away with straight lines in polar coordinates:

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x = category, y = value, group=1)) +
  coord_straightpolar(theta = 'x') +
  geom_area(color = 'blue', alpha = .00001) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Now to be fair, I don't know what the unintended consequences are for this change. At least now we know why ggplot behaves this way, and what we can do to avoid it.

EDIT: Unfortunately, I don't know of an easy/elegant way to connect the points across the axis limits but you could try code like this:

```
# Refactoring the data
dd <- data.frame(category = c(1,2,3,4), value = c(2, 7, 4, 2))

ggplot(dd, aes(x = category, y = value, group=1)) +
  coord_straightpolar(theta = 'x') +
  geom_path(color = 'blue') +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,4), breaks = 1:3, labels = LETTERS[1:3]) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Some discussion about polar coordinates and crossing the boundary, including my own attempt at solving that problem, can be seen here [geom_path() refuses to cross over the 0/360 line in coord_polar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132352/geom-path-refuses-to-cross-over-the-0-360-line-in-coord-polar/)

EDIT2:

I'm mistaken, it seems quite trivial anyway. Assume `dd` is your original tibble:

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x = category, y = value, group=1)) +
  coord_straightpolar(theta = 'x') +
  geom_polygon(color = 'blue', alpha = 0.0001) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The last issue to solve would be to fill the area between C-A (i.e. to have a straight line connecting those points).